# Is there any specific reasoning why C13/C14 power cord is used in almost all UPS devices as output?

Tags: ups, plug

Just bought another UPS for office and making wiring for it - cutting of standard plugs and installing C13 on extension cords.

Logical question arose - Why there are C14 on UPS output? Is there any reason for it?

**Edit:**

Reason for cutting power cords is simple - on each desk there are several things that need to be UPSed - PC, VoIP phone and basic desktop network switch. Later two use negligible amount of power and use standard power supplies, that cannot be plugged into UPS C14 socket. Besides it is easier to manage 4 cables for 4 desks instead of 12.

Comment: Because computers?

Comment: More international than 10+ different domestic plugs a UPS manufacturer needs to make specific models for?

Comment: It's also smaller than both BS and Euro sockets.

Comment: .. and another reason - it discourages people plugging in random appliances like vacuum cleaners into the UPS, thereby overloading it. For computers you should be buying 'native' C13/C14 leads.

Comment: @pjc50: which -- given the cutting of part he mentions -- I am wondering the OP is doing right now...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: See edited question.

Comment: @icebreaker: Usually people use one of these for at: http://www.partsdata.de/media/image/thumbnail/19-zoll-steckdosenleiste-8-fach-fuer-usv-mit-c14-stecker_KPW-219_1_720x600.jpg

Comment: I'll add another reason: Discourages people from adding power strips as C13/C14's apparently only allows for 1 device per UPS controlled outlet.

Comment: Also, if you are going to power devices further and further away from the UPS, I would start to worry about current loops.  You may not always be there to stop people from plugging into the UPS and into Mains then connect the equipment together.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks for link. I use black extension cords with refitted C13/C14 plug and marker UPS fitted to cable end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up what I got from comments. Reasoning behind C14 output on UPS:

- To discourage improper use (impossible to plug vacuum cleaner)
- It is more standardized than any country's plug
- It is more compact than most of mains plugs
- It is more convenient to use with computers